# Saving the context does not persist an updated NSManagedObject

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

In my app I have 2 detail view controllers:

- *product name update controller*
- *product properties update controller*

In *product properties update view controller* everything is fine there is nothing wrong.

In *product name update view controller* however saving the context does not give any error. I see that the product name change in root view controller but when I re-open my app the product name shows me the old name. So it is not persisted.

What is my problem according to my `updateProduct` method:

```
-(void)updateProduct:(id)sender
 {
AppDelegate *delegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [delegate managedObjectContext];

NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Products" inManagedObjectContext:context]];

NSError *error = nil;

NSPredicate *predicateID =[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"productID==%d",[secim intValue]];
[request setPredicate:predicateID];

NSArray *myobj=[context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
NSManagedObject *prod1=[myobj objectAtIndex:0];

[prod1 setValue:textProduct1.text forKey:@"productName"];



if (![context save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Can't Save! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
}


[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];

NSLog(@"Data saved");
}
```

Comment: Your AppDelegate code is irrelevant. Please delete it from the question.

Comment: Also check that 'prod1' is a valid object

Answer (score 0):

Check with a breakpoint if your `updateProduct` method is called. I suspect it is not.

In the light of the other discussion, make sure that

- the managed object context is not `nil`
- prod1 (the managed object) is not `nil`

You can do this with breakpoints in the debugger or with log statements.

Comment: when i debug the code it enters to the updateProduct method and finished successfully so it returns to the rootviewcontroller and the updated data shown in the rootviewcontroller BUT when i stop simulator from Xcode and bind it again the data returns to the old one. i think it saves to the context but not to the database or disk

Comment: Updated my answer with further instructions.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to **@Mundi** here you are doing the following

```
NSArray *myobj = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
NSManagedObject *prod1 = [myobj objectAtIndex:0];
```

but you are not checking against `error` and neither if `myobj` contains elements.

**ALWAYS** check for errors whereas there is the possibility to have them.

Comment: i think there is no error but to be sure if you tell me how can i checked if there is an error and what is the message i will write it too. but as i said before i debug the code and everything looks fine in context. if i stop the Xcode after update method successfully done and then run my code again the data gets old. so the problem is  context not save my data to the database or disk i think

Comment: @ercan Are you sure `prod1` is valid?

Comment: what do you mean by valid? would you give more detail?

Comment: @ercan Are you sure that before and after the `setValue:forKey` the obj has changed correctly? Put a log before and after to verify it.

Comment: ok i couldn't find what i write before and after but i open sqlite in firefox. and see that data not changed after context save works so it executes context save but cannot write to the .sqlite file